# Cuadricula con elementos de diferente tamaño con flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estoy creando una galería de imágenes con diferente tamaño usando flexbox, hasta ahora tengo un código que funciona bien pero ya no puedo agregarle mas elementos ya que se empiezan a posicionar encima de los demás y no entiendo por que

```css
.gallery-images .img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .gallery-images {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .row-images {
    display: flex;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .row-images {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .row-images {
    display: flex;
    height: 400px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .row-images {
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .column-1-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .column-2-3 {
    width: 66.67%;
  }
  .column-1-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
.img {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
}
.img-small {
  background-color: #90ee90;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-medium {
  background-color: #add8e6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-large {
  background-color: #ff6347;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-images">
  <div class="row-images">
    <div class="column-1-3">
      <div class="img img-small">Small</div>
      <div class="img img-small">Small</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2-3">
      <div class="img img-medium">Medium</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-images">
    <div class="column-2-3">
      <div class="row-images">
        <div class="column-1-2">
          <div class="img img-large">Large</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column-1-2">
          <div class="img img-small">Small</div>
          <div class="img img-small">Small</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-images">
        <div class="img img-medium">Medium</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-1-3">
      <div class="img img-small">Small</div>
      <div class="img img-large">Large</div>
      <div class="img img-small">Small</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-images">
    <div class="column-1-2">
      <div class="column-1-2">
        <div class="img img-small">Esto no deberia estar aqui</div>
        <div class="img img-small">Esto no deberia estar aqui</div>
      </div>
      <div class="column-1-2">
        <div class="img img-small">Esto no deberia estar aqui</div>
        <div class="img img-small">Esto no deberia estar aqui</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

no estoy seguro de a que layout quieres llegar, seria bueno que lo aclararas, pero mientras puedo sugerir algunas cosas:

declara `flex-flow`, sin esta propiedad flexbox no funciona adecuadamente:

```css
#elemento{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  /* "row", los elementos se alinean horizontalmente*/
  /* "wrap", si no caben forman otra linea*/
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

tambien ayúdate del `overflow`:

```css
*{
  overflow: auto;
  /* se añade a todos los elemento por defecto*/
}
#elemento{
  overflow: hidden;
  /* los elementos que se salgan del padre seran recortados*/
}
```

esto te permite controlar el flujo de los hijos.

otras propiedades que pueden ser utiles:

```css
*{
  position: relative;
  /*posicionamiento con respecto al padre*/
  height: auto;
  /*crecimiento con respecto al contenido*/
  display: block;
  /*te ahorras comportamientos propios de ciertos elementos*/
  /*se anula con display:inline-block;*/
}
```

estoy pendiente de tu actualización

Comment: @AXL El [voseo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo) es una forma de conjugación válida. Por favor, no modifiques las formas verbales a "tú" cuando el autor no las usa.